# Cannot update div style attributes

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change a couple of style attributes. Here is the style I first assigned to `clickedMenuHexagonDiv`:

```
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.MozTransform = "scale(.9999)";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.width = num2px(this.width);
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.marginRight = "3px";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.position = "relative";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.zIndex = "5";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.styleFloat = "right";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.cssFloat = "right";
```

Here is the code later on, for the attributes I want to change:

```
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.className = "centerHexagonDiv";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.bottom = "auto";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.right = "auto";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.float = "none";
alert("clickedMenuHexagonDiv: " + clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.cssText);
```

And here is the output of the alert:

```
clickedMenuHexagonDiv: transform: scale(0.9999); width: 80px; margin-right: 3px; position: relative; z-index: 5; float: right; right: auto; bottom: auto;
```

As you can see, it only updates attributes that weren't declared earlier. There were no console errors. Also, somewhat oddly, `bottom` and `right` were changed by the jquery animate function (I put an alert in before `clickedMenuHexagonDiv.className = "centerHexagonDiv";`, and it showed values other than "auto" for `bottom` and `right`.

I figured out that I can sort of fix this if I insert `clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.cssText = ""` before changing the style attributes, but then I have to declare all of the attributes again. I'd rather try to understand why I can't update specific attributes.

Comment: Sure seems like it would work -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9reSb/1/

Comment: I know, right? Maybe it's because it's in `$(clickedMenuHexagonDiv).promise().done(function() { `. I'll run a test and see what happens.

Comment: @adeneo That didn't work; if I get rid of the `$(clickedMenuHexagonDiv).promise().done(function() {} `, it doesn't update anything (the bottom and right aren't changed). It looks like another one of my functions is executing before this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If figured it out: I needed to use "styleFloat" and/or "cssFloat". "float" isn't a css property.

Here's the updated code (only the second section needed updating):

```
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.className = "centerHexagonDiv";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.bottom = "auto";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.right = "auto";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.styleFloat = "none";
clickedMenuHexagonDiv.style.cssFloat = "none";
```

Comment: probably worth adding your code, so the answer is complete (and easier for people to understand in the future).

Comment: i think you can also select your own answer - so the question gets closed as answered.